# Evaluating HAProxy and wondering about SSL?

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I'm evaluating an approporiate load balancer for a web project. The majority of the traffic to the site will be over ssl. I've read that HAProxy doesn't support ssl for various reasons. Are there ways to configure HAProxy so that it can handle and proxy traffic over https?

cheers,
Cathal.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will need to use an ssl offloaderin front of HaProxy, such as Pound or Stunnel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 1.5.x development version which supports SSL.